# HTML Email Contact Form

Tags: php, html, forms

Hi all I am new to PHP and seem to be going wrong somewhere while creating a contact form which emails responses to me.

My form is a standard form asking for name, email address, location and a message which is then forwarded to me as an email.

My PHP is:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['location'])  ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$location = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['location']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'to email';
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nLocation: $location\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: from email"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

My contact form has been working perfectly until I added the "location" section, following which it now fails and does not send the email to my inbox.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What are the errors that are being logged?

Comment: Sorry but excuse my ignorance, would I need to log this in php or check the log file on the web host?

Comment: search in the same folder from where you're running your php file. There might be a error_log file.